# Jquery datepicker send date to server with local time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to get date from a jquery datepicker and send it to server. I created a datepicker in the view then when trying getting the datepicker date the date returns with user local time for example

```
Date {Wed May 14 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)}
```

the problem here that their is a 2 hours delay between server and the time provided is there is any way to save data from datepicker as user selects it

Comment: What is the scripting language  btw?

Comment: mainly `jquery` there is other javascript libraries but in this issue i use only `jquery`

Comment: Can you post some example cases (of chosen dates and what should actually be chosen)?

Comment: chosen date Date {Wed May 14 2014 22:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)}  what sends to server May 14 2014 20:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [momentjs](http://www.momentjs.com/) to handle different timezones.

Comment: Great choice i am already using momentjs in my application but moment will format the date how to use it to fix this issue can you provide me a sample code for that

Comment: You can try something like this: `moment.unix(date).zone(0).format("HH:mm:ss")` you may have to modify the parameter of .zone()

Comment: but this formatted date is a string not a date object right?

Comment: Leave out the .format() and you should receive an object.

Comment: What is exactly not working? I cant provide another solution without detailed information. Please set up a jsfiddle.